# C# как посчитать строки между опредленными строками

Tags: c#, datagridview

Есть datagridveiw заполненный данными каждый в своей строке, колонка только одна. Данные вида

```
    *Вопрос
    A)ответ
    B)ответ
    C)ответ
    D)ответ
    + правильный ответ
    *Вопрос
    A)ответ
    B)ответ
    C)ответ
    D)ответ
    + правильный ответ
...
```

Ответов может быть 2 варианта может быть 10 как правильно посчитать количество вариантов ответа между вопросом и правельным ответом.

Comment: чем строка с вопросом отличается от строки с ответом или от строки с правильным ответом?

Comment: У вопроса * обязательно установлена в начале и у ответа + установлен в начале

Comment: 1 вопрос / ответ занимает только 1 строку? Есть многострочные вопросы / тветы? Если есть, то */- ставятся на каждой строке?

Comment: вопрос/ответ только по 1 строке занимают как показано в примере

Comment: ну то есть вы должны 1) Считать строки из вашего datagrid, если строка начинается с * - то это вопрос. Если с + - то правильный ответ. Если ни с *, ни с +, то вариант ответа. - вот вам и алгоритм для вашей программы

Comment: Да подсчет количества вариантов ответа в 1 вопросе хочу чтобы было

Comment: Чтобы например он показал всего вопросов 40 из них с 10 вариантами ответа столько с 3 столько и т.п.

Comment: Если бы я знал как это написать я бы тут не спрашивал -_-

Comment: ну я вам составил алгоритм, что нужно сделать, но если честно я бы не зотел писать код как ответ. Потому вы можете подождать, может кто то вам напишет готовый код, или вы можете попробовать решить задачу самостоятельно, и если не получится, то дописать вопрос своим кодом. Практика показала, что на вопросы с кодом отвечают чаще.

Comment: Алгоритм был составлен и без вас. Если вы не хотели писать ответ зачем начали отвечать в теме.

Comment: я решил, что вы не знаете, с чего начать, и решил немножко вам помочь. То, что алгоритм вы и так знали мне было не ясно из вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример построчного чтения с распознаванием типа строки

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                char firstSymbol = dgvr.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString()[0];
                if (firstSymbol == '*')
                {
                    //Вопрос
                }
                if (firstSymbol == '+')
                {
                    //Правильный ответ
                }
                if (firstSymbol != '*' && firstSymbol != '+')
                {
                    //Просто вопрос
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> text = new List<string>()
            {
                "*Вопрос", // 0
                "A)ответ",
                "B)ответ",
                "C)ответ",
                "D)ответ",
                "правильный ответ",
                "*Вопрос", // 6
                "A)ответ",
                "B)ответ",
                "C)ответ",
                "D)ответ",
                "правильный ответ",
                "*Вопрос", // 12
                "A)ответ",
                "B)ответ",
                "*Вопрос", // 15
                "A)ответ",
                "B)ответ",
                "A)ответ",
                "B)ответ",
                "A)ответ",
                "B)ответ",
                "A)ответ",
                "*Вопрос", // 23
                "B)ответ",
                "B)ответ",
                "B)ответ"
            };

            var indexses = text
                .Select((x, i) => x.StartsWith("*") ? i : -1)
                .Where(x => x >= 0)
                .ToList();

            // indexses.Add(text.Count - 1);

            var index = 0;

            while (index != indexses.Count - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Beetwen {Math.Abs((indexses[index] + 1) - indexses[index + 1])}");
                index++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Beetwen {Math.Abs((text.Count - 1) - indexses.Last())}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

ну и из каждой разницы вычесть 1 если  у вопроса  есть ответ который помещен как правильный

Answer (score 0):

*Вариант с zip*

```
        var results = text
            .Select((x,i) => x.StartsWith("*")?i:-1)
            .Where((i) => i != -1)
            .Zip(text
                .Select((x,i) => x.StartsWith("+")?i:-1)
                .Where((i) => i != -1),
                (curr, prev) =>prev - curr - 1)
            .ToList();
        foreach(var res in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]